# Adding a new additional method to existing nuget package

Tags: c#, nuget

I'd like to ask whether is it possible to write a extension method for existing nuget package (In my case it is Trimble Connect nuget with Api Connection) ? I'd like to do filetring option, but this nugetdoesnt offer a method like filtering...

Was looking for answer in web but not found.

Comment: Yes, you can write an extension-method for any instance-type. But the usual limitations of extension-methods always apply: you can't define extension-properties, and you can't define extension-methods on `static` types, and if an updated library introduces a non-extension method that conflicts with your extension, then the library method will always be preferred (unless you invoke your extension-method using a normal static invocation syntax).

Comment: you don't extend a *package*, but instead a *type within a package*. Having said this nuget doesn't "offer any method". Your question is pretty unclear, at least to me. Please show what you want to achieve actually.

Comment: the question still makes no sense, because you cannot extend a package. How do you want to call that "extension-method"? Please write an example how you want to use that function. Maybe that makes it clearer what you want to achieve.

Comment: from what I read in the comments it seems you just want to write some function that uses trimble-API. So create a method in your own class and call the API there. No need to *extend* anything.

Answer (score 1):

You can write an extension method to a type in nuget, if that is what you are trying to achieve - then yes, basically that is the main goal of [extension methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods):

> Extension methods enable you to "add" methods to existing types without creating a new derived type, recompiling, or otherwise modifying the original type.

So the "ownership" of the type does not matter - it can be a type from your own library/project or from 3rd party nuget, or even one of the build-in types like `string` (example from the linked earlier docs):

```cs
namespace ExtensionMethods
{
    public static class MyExtensions
    {
        public static int WordCount(this string str)
        {
            return str.Split(new char[] { ' ', '.', '?' },
                             StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Length;
        }
    }
}
```

```cs
using ExtensionMethods;

string s = "Hello Extension Methods";
int i = s.WordCount();
```

And you can define an extension method for applicable types from the nuget. Note that what the extension method can do is limited by the
API of the class it interacts with.

If the question is - *"can I make library to understand the arbitrary thing I want it to do"*, then answer would be: it depends on how extensible the library was designed and what extensibility points it has. Quite good examples (but maybe still not ideal) of extensibility would be the frameworks like ASP.NET Core and EF Core, which allows to do quite a lot.

Comment: I have the feeling that OPs problem is some misunderstanding of what a package is and how nuget is involved. It's pretty unclear what OP wants to achieve.

Comment: Im sorry i think i wrote wrong. I am using a Trimble Connect nuget package and it contain trimble API. I'd like to extend existing methods, because basically this nuget doesnt offer a "FilteringMethod" so i'd like to write it on my own. Is it possible ?

Comment: @JJablonski - Then ask that in your question. Read [ask] and edit your question please.

Comment: @JJablonski if question is - _"can I make library to understand the arbitrary thing I want it to do"_ - then answer is - it depends on how extensible the library is designed.

Comment: Actually in this library as can I see I can not do any changes or override methods. I can just use methods that are contained in this library.

Comment: @JJablonski overriding is not the only option which can be exposed by library for extensibility. For example as mentioned EF Core does - it exposes interceptors which allow to modify the behaviour. Another point of extensibility could be some special interfaces exposed and understood by library.

Comment: @JJablonski - I don't think you actually read [ask].